# How to achieve multiple return values in C# like python style

Tags: c#, python, function

I have a python script:

```
def f():
    a = None
    b = None
    return (a, b)


a, b = f()
```

It's so easy to achieve multiple return values in python.
And now I want to achieve the same result in C#. I tried several ways, like return int[] or KeyValuePair. But both ways looked not elegant. I wonder a exciting solution. thanks a lot.

Comment: The Tuple class is a little more elegant, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: Are multiple return values a good and desirable thing? Should functions be able to return anonymous types?

Comment: You might try F#, which supports this: `let f() = (14, 29)` then `let (a, b) = f()`

Comment: @Jodrell they are very useful indeed.  F#, for example, handles `TryParse` much more concisely than C#, because it returns out parameters as part of a tuple: `let (success, result) = Int32.TryParse(someString)`

Comment: @phoog, on consideration, I'm inclined to agree, as long as the types in the tuple are defined, unlike the OPs example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, C# does not support this. The closest you can get is to use `out` parameters:

```
void f(out int a, out int b) {
    a = 42;
    b = 9;
}

int a, b;
f(out a, out b);
```

Comment: does it like the reference parameter passing？

Comment: @JunHU: I don't understand - what is "it"?

Answer (score 6):

Use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class.

```
  public Tuple<int,int> f()
  {
        Tuple<int,int> myTuple = new Tuple<int,int>(5,5);
        return myTuple;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can obviously do

```
object F(out object b)
{
    b = null;
    return null
}

object b;
var a = F(out b)
```

but better to use `Tuple` with a functional style,

```
Tuple<object, object> F()
{
    return Tuple.Create<object, object>(null, null);
}

var r = F();
var a = r.Item1;
var b = r.Item2;
```

but, since in c# you can be explicit, why not define your return type.

```
struct FResult
{
    public object A;
    public object B;
}

FResult F()
{
    return new FResult();
}

var r = F();
var a = F.A;
var b = F.B;
```

This seems like a small price to pay for the semantic benefits.

Comment: F# is type safe, but you can also have `let f x = (x*2, x*x)` and `let (a, b) = f 5`, which assigns the values 10 and 25 to a and b, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in C#7 with .Net 4.7.

```
private (string a, string b) f()
{
    return (a: null, b: null);
    // or simply: return (null, null);
}

var (a, b) = f();
```